# Top users not updated for about a month

Tags: bug, status-review, top-users

... while the page claims it is updated daily.

What I have tried is to load [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/topusers), but the numbers are old by a month.

Comment: While this is very likely related to "[The tag scores have stopped incrementing](/q/427624)", which describes that the user's individual tag scores on their profile page have not updated, and does, probably, have the same cause for the problem, the question isn't a duplicate, as the issue is on a different page affecting a different display. IMO, it would be better to provide SE with all the information as to what's going wrong, so they can look into it, rather than not provide that information because we've assumed it's caused by the same thing (even though that's quite likely in this case).

Comment: To verify this I looked at both the [Top JavaScript Answerers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/topusers), both "Last 30 Days" and "All Time", rather than those for Prolog, as [archive.org has a much more comprehensive set of captures for the JavaScript page](https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/topusers).

Comment: I also see this in different tags, following this thread

Comment: I think this is fixed. Can you double-check on your end?

Comment: Yes, it is, thanks Spencer!

Comment: @SpencerG: Thank you and all who worked on fixing this.